# Read multiple excel files in multiple subdirectories in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a "Data" folder which has 15 years of data with year as folder name each of which have months as folders, each of months have 30 data files.

All files have same format. I am trying to read all files in python to build a time series. I need to build a dataframe which combines all the data.Tried a bunch of packages but still struggling.

Comment: Show us what you tried to do and where did it go wrong. Also you need to provide sample inputs and what you expect the output to be. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recursively curl using a nested for-loop and os.listdir()

First I created this folder structure to test:

```
data:
   2020
      January
         01.0_file.csv
         02.0_file.csv
      February
         01.0_file.csv
         02.0_file.csv
   2021
      January
         01.0_file.csv
         02.0_file.csv
      February
         01.0_file.csv
         02.0_file.csv
```

Nested for-loop and os.listdir():

```
import os  # we will need this module
data_path = "/home/stack_overflow/data"  # set the path where you want to start

data_directory_list = os.listdir(data_path)  # saves all sub directories in a list. (years)
for current_year in data_directory_list:  # loop over each year
    year_directory_path = data_path + "/" + current_year  # temporary path for each year
    sub_directories_year = os.listdir(year_directory_path)  # list all sub directories of year (month)
    for current_month in sub_directories_year:  # loop over each month
        month_directory_path = year_directory_path + "/" + current_month  # temporary path for each month
        all_files = os.listdir(month_directory_path)  # list of all files
        for file in all_files:  # temporary path for each file
            file_path =  month_directory_path + "/" + file
            print(file_path)
```

in file_path you will have each file once. Output:

```
/home/stack_overflow/data/2021/February/02.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2021/February/01.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2021/January/02.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2021/January/01.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2020/February/02.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2020/February/01.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2020/January/02.0_file.csv
/home/stack_overflow/data/2020/January/01.0_file.csv
```

Comment: what does curl have to do with this? also your code doesn't do what was asked in the question (combining data from several files to one dataframe)

Answer (score -1):

Use python to achieve your goal. Here is a sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
xlsx_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"), recursive=True)

for f in csv_files:
  df = pd.read_csv(f)
    
  print('Location:', f)
  print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
    
  print('Content:')
  display(df)
  print()
```